# OSG: Camera flight with AnimationPathManipulator

Tags: c++, 3d, openscenegraph

I'm trying to apply an osg::AnimationPath to the camera of my osgViewer::Viewer instance by using an osgGA::AnimationPathManipulator. My problem is that the AnimationPathManipulator only applies the change of rotation and no change of position to the camera. So it only rotates but doesn't translate.

I am using OpenSceneGraph Library 3.0.1.

For a better insight, this is my current code:

```
void CameraFlyTest::animateCamera(osgViewer::Viewer* viewer) {

  osg::AnimationPath* path = new osg::AnimationPath();
  path->setLoopMode(osg::AnimationPath::SWING);

  osg::AnimationPath::ControlPoint cp1;
  cp1.setPosition(osg::Vec3d(-200,-450,60));
  cp1.setRotation(osg::Quat(M_PI_2, osg::Vec3(1,0,0)));

  osg::AnimationPath::ControlPoint cp2;
  cp2.setPosition(osg::Vec3d(2000,-500,60));
  cp2.setRotation(osg::Quat(M_PI_4, osg::Vec3(1,0,0)));

  path->insert(1.0f,cp1);
  path->insert(3.0f,cp2);

  osgGA::AnimationPathManipulator* apm = new osgGA::AnimationPathManipulator(path);
  viewer->setCameraManipulator(apm);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that another active camera manipulator has also updated the position of the camera. The osgGA::AnimationPathManipulator itself works as it should.